# IOS: Tokenizer on UITextInput is never called

Tags: ios, tokenize, core-text, uitextinput, uikeyinput

I have a UITextInput implementation with one small problem that seems to be screwing up my ability have good AutoCapitalization:

The tokenizer property never gets called (even after calling becomeFirstResponder), so my Custom Tokenizer never gets instantiated or used.

```
- (id<UITextInputTokenizer>)tokenizer {
NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
if (tokenizer == nil) {
    tokenizer = [MyCustomTokenizer alloc] initWithTextInput:self];
}
return tokenizer;
```

Does anybody have any idea why this would happen?

More info that may help: The UITextInput implementation is on a subclass of UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was returning Nil for the selectedTextRange when I should have been returning a selection of length 0.